# Faster equivalent of SQL Server IN clause for many values

Tags: .net, sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using OrmLite .NET with SQL Server 12.0. I want to select entities where a certain integer column (not the primary key) has one of many values, which I have in an array. An OrmLite expression like this:

```
q => query.Where(r => myIntegers.Contains(r.TheColumn))
```

gets translated to

```
WHERE "TheColumn" IN (1, 2, 3, ...) -- my integers
```

This works fine with ~100, but times out with 1000. How do I achieve the same effect with a larger list? Can I pass an array to SQL Server somehow or a table parameter?

Comment: convert your array in a subquery or with creation of temp table to join with the others table of your query

Comment: SQL Server does support table-valued parameters.. but I have no idea about OrmLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what @JoeTaras commented, you can put the acceptable values into a subquery, something like;

```
SELECT TheColumn from TheTable T
INNER JOIN (SELECT * from (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) as V1(value)) V
ON T.TheColumn = V.value
```

Comment: I know nothing of OrmLite so take this with a grain of salt. For this to work, wouldn't the sql in the answer need to be in a view in the database, then mapped to some entity? Then you'd include that entity in the OP's linq query?

Answer (score 1):

In OrmLite you may build raw SQL query you need (for example, from @Sam cd answer) and pass it to `db.Select` method:

```
string joinedIds = string.Join("),(", new List<int> {1, 2, 9});

string command =
    $"SELECT * from Employee AS E INNER JOIN (SELECT * from (VALUES( {joinedIds} )) as TV(value)) V ON E.Id = V.value";

List<Employee> employers = db.Select<Employee>(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a temporary table for this, i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE #ParamTempTable (Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #ParamTempTable (Id) VALUES ((1), (2), (3));

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM #ParamTempTable);

DROP TABLE #ParamTempTable;
```

I do this only when I have > 1000 values, otherwise I just use `SQL IN (1, 2, 3)`.

To implement this on OrmLite I had to subclass `SqlServerExpression<T>` and override `VisitStaticArrayMethodCall` and `VisitEnumerableMethodCall` to change how it handled `Contains` expressions. This class stores the commands to create and drop the temp tables separately and I have to run separate a `SqlCommand` for each of those. (`CREATE TABLE` doesn't work in `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`, unfortunately.) So this ended up being quite complicated, but it does work and is transparent to the caller. An added benefit is that I could eliminate duplicate parameters, so e.g. for `o => ids.Contains(o.FromId) || ids.Contains(o.ToId)` the list `ids` gets sent to SQL server only once.